# How to to get time slice in raster dataset using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, time

I have a couple of rasters made in different time. Some of the rasters are overlapping and some of them - not.

I need fast and efficient way to get time sliced values for each pixel.

For example:

```
    pixel # 1
    value: 255         200         150
     date: 01.01.2015  02.01.2015  02.01.2015 

    pixel # 2
    value: 240         250         160
     date: 03.02.2015  04.02.2015  05.02.2015

    and so on ...
```

[image]

There are any tools for this task in ArcGIS, ArcPy?

I am sure first step should be put those rasters in raster dataset or mosaic dataset. But I can't proceed further.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array of values once you have it?

Comment: I need to analyse each array to detect anomaly values (in comparison with all other values in array). The idea is to create a change detection algorithm using a huge amount of data.

Comment: ArcGIS has no array datatype (AFAIK), unlike Postgres, which I'd possibly recommend, depending on the size of your rasters. The Data Management tool `Composite Bands` will make you a multiband raster, but I don't think it will be great for a large number of rasters.

Comment: Multiband rasters will get extent of all rasters in collection so huge amount of Nodata values will appear. This will significantly increase size. Mosaic dataset storage system not influenced by this issue. So `Composite Bands` is not a way out in my situation.